# grails 2.2.4 one-to-many not query using criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain structure like :

```
class Conversation{
static hasMany=[receivers:User]

}
```

and

```
class User{
    String username
    ....     
}
```

and I want to find the conversation which doesn't belong to a particular User.(Using criteria not HQL)

I tried the following queries but i get the empty set.

```
def user=User.get(3)

Conversation.createCriteria().list{
       receivers{
 //all options didn't work for me...
 //ne('id',user.id) 
//not{eq('id',user.id)}
not{'inList'('id',[user.id])}

        }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would use HQL

```
Conversation.executeQuery("select c from Conversation c left join c.receivers as receivers where :user not in receivers",[user: User.get(3)])
```